# graph of the average in a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a task which says "Generate $1000$ equally distributed $[-1,1]$ random variables and draw the graph of the average $X_n$.

Sounds simple enough but I can't quite figure what they mean by the average $X_n$ - I could just get the arithmetic average of the 1000 results, but that would give me just one value of ~ $E(X) = 0$ and the graph would be constant. That sounds just a bit too straight forward considering my next task would be to do the same on a cauchy distribution.

Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you studying the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: Yeah but the central limit theorem only concerns normal distribution approximation as far as I understand

Comment: What you are missing is $\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \neq \mathbb{E}[X]$. It is a.s. equal when $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Well yeah it will aproach $E(X)$ - but is this really the core of the task, because all I would do is drawing two constant graphs.

Comment: I think what you're asked then is to plot $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$, up to $n$. Otherwise, CLT says that the $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \sim \text{Normal}$. Possible useful resource: http://www.statisticalengineering.com/central_limit_theorem.htm

Comment: okay I think I got it, I have to plot the probablity density function of $X_n$ - Is there any smart way to do this apart from using a numerical program, we never did that so I don't think we are allowed to...

I tried using the characteristic function which is fairly simpe $\phi (t) = sin(t)/t$ but I could not reverse because I could not solve the integral.